# What will happen when Corda controller node stops? Can other nodes still communicate?

Tags: corda

I am using release-v1 of Corda.

My app has four nodes - Controller (provides network map service and validating notary service), A, B and C. Following are the flows defined in the app -

Flow 1: A sends a trade request to B and C

Flow 2: B approves the trade request, self-signs it, gets signature from A and closes the trade.

What will happen when the Controller node stops or disconnects when one of the above flows is initiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using Corda 3+ (preferably Corda 4) and not v1.

If the node providing the Notary service went down, then any transactions requiring a notaries signature will not finish until it comes back up. They will remain suspended until the Notary restarts. Once it does, the flows that have been suspended will wake up and continue running.

Not 100% sure what happens if the network map goes down. I think the nodes will continue to work with each other since they have a cache of the acceptable nodes to communicate with.

Comment: Thank you for reply